# Any concerns about branching/merging projects with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, tfs, branch

I'm about to branch a project that uses EF.  I know that there will be a modicum of changes in the trunk, as well as many changes in the branch.  I will need to merge in changes from the trunk into the branch from time to time.

I'm not concerned about the straight up C# code that usese EF objects (Linq to Entities) I'm concerned about the entity model itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The branching / merging / and concurrent development story for EF entity models is a known sore spot. I think you are just going to have to manually merge the differences in the cases when automerge fails. Alternatively, you could go with the code only approach added in EF 4 and forget about entity models altogether.

You may want to check out this related question if you haven't already:

[Entity Framework Merge Nightmare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434554/entity-framework-merge-nightmare)

Comment: This is very unfortunate. I gather from your answer that apart from a code-only approach, there is no other improvment on this issue with EF4?

Comment: I haven't tried a project with EF4 yet, but I've been following it pretty closely. There have been several features added to the model designer, but I have not seen anything that indicates that merge scenarios will be any different.

Comment: Ralph,I'm not sure which merge tool you use, but is merging XML really such a big problem? In the four months or so since I wrote that answer, and following the strategy I outlined there, I haven't seen an automated merge of EDMX fail, ever.