# Merging EMDX (Entity Framework) files with Git

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git, entity-framework

As a team we are finding it difficult/impossible to merge EDMX files between branches and are considering a policy that all EDMX changes have to occur in the master branch.  Has anyone encountered this issue, and how is your team handling it?

Comment: see [Entity Framework Merge Nightmare](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1434554)

Comment: `git` is geared towards version control of files in which small changes can be sensibly described as a few lines added/changed/deleted. Any sort of file where this isn't true (typically XML descriptions of stuff nowadays) isn't handled well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework Merge Nightmare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434554/entity-framework-merge-nightmare)