# Entity Framework - how to work with the EDMX file in Git

Tags: git, entity-framework, bitbucket

Hi I'm going to be using database first EF. It's a bit old school but is a good fit for what we as a team want. I can imagine the EDMX file has the potential for merge conflicts. We use Git/Bitbucket - can anyone recommend the "safest" way of dealing with this. I'm not a Git expert but I'm open to suggestions. Cheers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework Merge Nightmare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434554/entity-framework-merge-nightmare)